# What is Performance Counter and how to use them in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, performance, counter

What is Performance Counter and how to use them in ASP.NET application.

Please explain.

Comment: This post is way too broad and could be answered with a simple Google search. I don't advocate Google on most SO questions, but this is entirely too broad.

Comment: Dear @Scott if we have to use Google then we don't need this forum. For you this is a too broad but for others it is not, that's why this question has getting answers by other users. Negative vote is not fare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373083.aspx):

> Counters are used to provide information as to how well the operating system or an application, service, or driver is performing. The counter data can help determine system bottlenecks and fine-tune system and application performance. The operating system, network, and devices provide counter data that an application can consume to provide users with a graphical view of how well the system is performing.

The .NET framework has several classes that allow you to use and create performance counters, the main ones are the [`PerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx), [`PerformanceCounterCategory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecountercategory.aspx)
and [`CounterCreationData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.countercreationdata.aspx) (for creating new counters).

From the documentation on the `System.Diagnostics` namespace:

> The PerformanceCounter class enables you to monitor system performance, while the PerformanceCounterCategory class provides a way to create new custom counters and categories. You can write to local custom counters and read from both local and remote counters (system as well as custom). You can sample counters using the PerformanceCounter class, and calculate results from successive performance counter samples using the CounterSample class. The CounterCreationData class enables you to create multiple counters in a category and specify their types. Other classes associated with the performance counter component provide access to collections of counters, counter permission, and counter types.

Answer (score 1):

Refer here.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4.aspx